# batch file - 'The Syntax of the command is incorrect'

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've been making a text-adventure, but towards the end of my coding it came up with this error. Every time I try to continue from scene 5 to scene 5.1 it goes to a different scene and skips through it. Help?

Here is my code:

```os
cls
echo You walk in through the doorframe, and into the dark room. You can't see a thing in the gloom, but when you put your hand on the wall you recognise the shape of a lightswitch.
echo.
pause
goto scene5.1

cls
echo You walk in through the doorframe, and into the dark room. You can't see a thing in the gloom, but when you put your hand on the wall you recognise the shape of a lightswitch.
echo.
pause
goto scene5.1

:scene5.1
cls
echo You flip the lightswitch down, and slowly the glowing bulbs switch on; illuminating the living room. In the gradually increasing light you see a table in the corner, and a large sofa that streches across the back wall. A few metres in front of the couch is a fireplace.
echo.
echo 1) Table
echo 2) Sofa
echo 3) Fireplace
echo 4) Go back
set /p type
if %type%==1 goto scene5.1.1
if %type%==2 goto scene5.1.2
if %type%==3 goto scene5.1.3
if %type%==4 goto scene5.1.4
```

Comment: Instead of `set /P type`, write `set /P type=`... and you need to define what should happen if the user types anything else than `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, perhaps by a simple `goto scene5.1` loop-back after the `if` statements... I recommend to put `set type=` before the `set /P` command in order to erase the `type` variable... finally, escape all the closing parenthesis like `^)`, because otherwise they might close blocks `()` of code unintentionally...

Comment: Also, `goto :label` is nicer syntax. Another note is `echo.`'s  [occasional errors](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4554) and a slower command time because `echo.` looks for a file named "echo." without an extension.  `echo:` is generally faster and more reliable, as `:` is invalid in paths, so CMD ignores the search.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Windows\system32>echo 4) Go back
4) Go back

C:\Windows\system32>set /p type
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
goto was unexpected at this time.
```

It's probably the lack of an equals sign in `set /p` (well I know it is).

PS: `Set /p var = PromptText` is not the best command. It doesn't prevent wrong entry, and you don't check for it. Use `Choice` command instead. It only takes allowed entry.

The reason most examples use set /p is because choice was dropped from one windows version 15 years ago. That was along time ago.

```
CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]

Description:
    This tool allows users to select one item from a list
    of choices and returns the index of the selected choice.

Parameter List:
   /C    choices       Specifies the list of choices to be created.
                       Default list is "YN".

   /N                  Hides the list of choices in the prompt.
                       The message before the prompt is displayed
                       and the choices are still enabled.

   /CS                 Enables case-sensitive choices to be selected.
                       By default, the utility is case-insensitive.

   /T    timeout       The number of seconds to pause before a default
                       choice is made. Acceptable values are from 0 to
                       9999. If 0 is specified, there will be no pause
                       and the default choice is selected.

   /D    choice        Specifies the default choice after nnnn seconds.
                       Character must be in the set of choices specified
                       by /C option and must also specify nnnn with /T.

   /M    text          Specifies the message to be displayed before
                       the prompt. If not specified, the utility
                       displays only a prompt.

   /?                  Displays this help message.

   NOTE:
   The ERRORLEVEL environment variable is set to the index of the
   key that was selected from the set of choices. The first choice
   listed returns a value of 1, the second a value of 2, and so on.
   If the user presses a key that is not a valid choice, the tool
   sounds a warning beep. If tool detects an error condition,
   it returns an ERRORLEVEL value of 255. If the user presses
   CTRL+BREAK or CTRL+C, the tool returns an ERRORLEVEL value
   of 0. When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, list
   them in decreasing order.

Examples:
   CHOICE /?
   CHOICE /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
   CHOICE /T 10 /C ync /CS /D y
   CHOICE /C ab /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
   CHOICE /C ab /N /M "Select a for option 1 and b for option 2."
```

As help says use errorlevels in descending order

```
if errorlevel 4 dosomething
if errorlevel 3 dosomething
if errorlevel 2 dosomething
if errorlevel 1 dosomething
if errorlevel 0 UserPressedCtrl+C
```

or in any order

```
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 dosomething for 1
```

Do not use `%errorlevel%` as it can be overwritten by other programs.

Comment: I'm glad, they reinserted `choice` to Windows. Btw: `goto :scene5.1.%errorlevel%` seems a logical thing to do.

Comment: Unless another of the millions of programs that exist has overridden it.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! You have saved Darkness Falls! (The name of the adventure).

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:scene4.6.1
:scene5.1
SET "scene=5.1"
cls
echo You flip the lightswitch down, and slowly the glowing bulbs switch on; illuminating the living room. In the gradually increasing light you see a table in the corner, and a large sofa that streches across the back wall. A few metres in front of the couch is a fireplace.
echo.
CALL :addchoice Table Sofa Fireplace "Go back"

GOTO makechoice

:scene5.1.1
ECHO AT table
goto :eof

:scene5.1.2
ECHO AT sofa
goto :eof

:scene5.1.3
ECHO AT fireplace
goto :eof

:scene5.1.4
:scene4.6
SET "scene=4.6"
echo You are IN a dank corridor dimly lit by sputtering torches
echo.
CALL :addchoice Doorway Corridor
GOTO makechoice


:makechoice
CHOICE /C %choices% 
SET "scene=%scene%.%errorlevel%"
SET /a choicecount=0
SET "choices="
GOTO scene%scene%

:addchoice
SET /a choicecount+=1
ECHO %choicecount%) %~1
SET "choices=%choices%%choicecount%"
SHIFT
IF "%~1" neq "" GOTO addchoice

GOTO :EOF
```

This may save you a heap of programming. Please do not accept it as an answer since `bgalea's` answer actually answers your question. This is just an approach to make the construct-an-adventure exercise faster and easier.

For each scene, describe the scene and call `:addchoice` with parameters of the available choices. If a choice is multiple words, "enclose them in quotes".

The routine assigns `1` to the first choice in the list, `2` to the next and so on. The available choices are then recorded in `choices`.

go to `makechoice`. This prompts for an entry using the list in `choices`. Then append dot+the `errorlevel` of the response to the current scene number, clear the choices and goto `scene`+the calculated scene number.

Note that you can use an empy command-sequence to move between scenes by using the structure like in scene5.1.4 to scene4.6 (iow, scene 5.1+choice4 moves to 4.6)

This way, your response-sets become one line after your scene description and you never need to use a series of if-commands to move between scenes.